# Cradle / Express / EJS convert html to its entities

Tags: node.js, express, ejs, cradle

I'm using Cradle with Express and EJS on my blog. Maybe i am missing smth but some of them converts html entities to its equivalents.

I have html in doc.quote field and after this piece of code it changes

```
quotesDb.view('list/by_date', {
    'startkey' : {},
    'endkey' : null,
    'descending' : true
}, function(err, res) {
    if (err) {
        r.send();
        return;
    }

    r.partial('quotes', {'quotes' : res}, function(err, str) {
        console.log(str);
        sendResponse('content', str);
    });
});
```

quotes.ejs:

```
<% for (var i=0; i<quotes.length; i++) { %>
    <div>
        <%=quotes[i].value.quote%>
    </div>
    <div class="date">
        <%=(new Date(quotes[i].value.ts*1000)).toLocaleDateString()%><% if (quotes[i].value.author) { %>, <%=quotes[i].value.author%><% } %>
    </div>
<% } %>
```

"res" variable is array which has objects with "content" field (which has html). But after rendering "str" has "quotes[i].value.quote" symbols converted to its entities, say <br> to &lt ; br &gt ;

Comment: it's definitely EJS. The question is: how to let it render data without converting it to its entities.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer was found here:
http://groups.google.com/group/express-js/browse_thread/thread/f488d19a1604c30e?pli=1

For rendering with escaping:

```
<%=var%>
```

---

For rendering without escaping:

```
<%-var%>
```